# How to add new user control in TabControl.ContentTemplate?

Tags: wpf, templates, tabcontrol

I am little stuck with adding new instances of a usercontrol in a `TabControl.ContentTemplate`?

My Xaml is here:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type uc:mytest1}">
            <uc:mytest1>

            </uc:mytest1>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

I am binding `TabControl.ItemsSource` property to an `ObservableCollection` and in the content template I am adding a user control, but when this app runs I am getting new items as `TabItem`s but the content page is holding same user control, but I want new user controls to be added for each new `TabItem`.

I am very new to the WPF and may be I am doing a very basic mistake, kindly guide me.

Answer (score 7):

The `ControlTemplate` determines the appearance of the elements of the tab control that are not part of the individual tab items. The `ItemTemplate` handles the content of the individual tab items. Additionally, a `TabItem` is a headered content control, which means it has two content type properties `Content` and `Header` with two separate templates `ContentTemplate` and `HeaderTemplate`. In order to be able to populate the tab items using binding, you need to style the `TabItem` using the above properties.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="Example.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Name="Window"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding ElementName="Window" Path="VM"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemHeaderTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemContentTemplate">
            <Ellipse Fill="Green"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="TabItemContainerStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}"/>
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" 
                    Value="{StaticResource TabItemHeaderTemplate}"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
                    Value="{StaticResource TabItemContentTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItemContainerStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public TabControlVM VM { get; set; }

    public Window2()
    {
        VM = new TabControlVM();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And the view model classes:

```
public class TabControlVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<TabItemVM> Items { get; set; }

    public TabControlVM()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<TabItemVM>();
        Items.Add(new TabItemVM("tabitem1"));
        Items.Add(new TabItemVM("tabitem2"));
        Items.Add(new TabItemVM("tabitem3"));
        Items.Add(new TabItemVM("tabitem4"));
    }
}

public class TabItemVM
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public TabItemVM(string header)
    {
        Header = header;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Saurabh, When you set Template, usually DataTemplate, ControlTemplate etc, the visual elements inside these templates are reused in WPF with concept of UI Virtualization. TabControl typically displays only one item at a time, so it does not create new Visual Item for every tab item, instead it only changes that DataContext and refreshes bindings of "Selected Visual Item". Its loaded/unloaded events are fired, but the object is same always.

You can use loaded/unload events and write your code accordingly that your "Visual Element" which is your usercontrol, so that control should be stateless and is not dependent on old data. When new DataContext has applied you should refresh everything.

DataContextChanged, Loaded and Unloaded events can help you remove all dependencies on old data.

Otherwise, you an create a new TabItem manually with your UserControl as its Child and add it in TabControl instead of adding Data Items.

Adding TabItems manually will create new control for every item and in selected area different elements will appear based on selection.