# WPF : Is it possible to use a data template and a control template?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, controltemplate

I'm currently working on styling a TabControl, and have a maybe weird idea :

What if I would like to have a default ControlTemplate for all my tabs in my application, but specify a different DataTemplate for each TabControl (depending on the data I want to show)?

What do you think of that? Do you know if there's a solution for this?

Maybe I'm taking the wrong way...

Thank you for your thoughts :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way!
In fact, the ItemContainerStyle property of the TabControl provide three templates :

1. HeaderTemplate, which is a data template for the header of each item
2. ContentTemplate, which is a data template for the content of each item
3. Template, which can be a control template, and which is the one I'm using!

Here's how I do it (the style) :

```
<Style x:Key="MyTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template"  
            Value="{StaticResource ControlTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate"  
            Value="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"  
            Value="{StaticResource ContentTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

And to link it to the TabControl :

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" 
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyTabItemStyle}">
```

What do you think of that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify a DataTemplate for a TabControl you specify a DataTemplate for the data that is displayed **in** all TabItems of your TabControl.

Comment: Hi Bitbonk, I actually use the ItemContainerStyle property of the TabControl to set the "HeaderTemplate" and the "ContentTemplate" (both are DataTemplate) (see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965355/how-to-add-new-user-control-in-tabcontrol-contenttemplate, first answer), and I'd like to add a ControlTemplate to them.